# Running total of positive and negative numbers where the sum cannot go below zero

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is an SQL question.

I have a column of numbers which can be positive or negative, and I'm trying to figure out a way to have a running sum of the column, but where the total cannot go below zero.

```
Date       | Number | Desired | Actual
2020-01-01 |    8   |   8     |    8
2020-01-02 |   11   |  19     |   19
2020-01-03 |   30   |  49     |   49
2020-01-04 |  -10   |  39     |   39
2020-01-05 |  -12   |  27     |   27
2020-01-06 |   -9   |  18     |   18
2020-01-07 |  -26   |   0     |   -8
2020-01-08 |    5   |   5     |   -3
2020-01-09 |  -23   |   0     |  -26
2020-01-10 |   12   |  12     |  -14
2020-01-11 |   14   |  26     |    0
```

I have tried a number of different window functions on this, but haven't found a way to prevent the running total from going into negative numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT - Added a date column to indicate the ordering

Comment: I assume you have a column that specifies the ordering, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: I added a date column to make it clear that, yes, the ordering will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this without cycling through the records one-by-one.  That, in turn, requires something like a recursive CTE.

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ),
     cte as (
      select NULL as number, 0 as desired, 0 as seqnum
      union all
      select t.number,
             (case when cte.desired + t.number < 0 then 0
                   else cte.desired + t.number
              end),
             cte.seqnum + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where cte.number is not null;
```

I would recommend this approach only if your data is rather small. But then again, if you have to do this, there are not many alternatives other then going through the table row-by-agonizing-row.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2a64d11ac21fe98c3ee7d79aa1d2b2c) is a db<>fiddle (using Postgres).

Comment: Hmmm... yes, this might actually work for my problem.  It's a fairly limited number of records as it's run on the results of an aggregation query.  I'll give it a test, thanks.

Comment: Actually there are a few problems here... one is simple, there's a missing parenthesis after "cte as".  The second one is that there is no "number" field in "cte", so the query will fail. 
 This is fixed by changing "select NULL, 0 as desired" to "select NULL as number, 0 as desired".  The third problem is more difficult:  The join used ("join t.seqnum on cte.seqnum + 1") references the field "cte.seqnum", except... there is no seqnum field in cte.  In fact there isn't a third field.

Comment: @Momus . . . Thank you for the feedback.  It is fixed.  I added a db<>fiddle to show that it works.

Comment: Wow.  This is pretty brilliant man.  I actually added the seqnum field to the query with "select NULL as number, 0 as desired, 0 as seqnum" and adding "cte.seqnum" to the cte query, but I didn't figure out that it needed to be "cte.seqnum + 1".  Thanks, marking this as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE operator and the SIGN function to do so…

```
CASE SIGN(my computed expression) WHEN -1 THEN 0 ELSE my computed expression END AS Actual
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain the result of this would be [8,19,49,39,27,18,0,0,0,0,0] since the sum aggregation would still be calculating negative numbers, but would be displaying them as zeroes.  The last 5 numbers need to be [...0,5,0,12,26] -- for example it needs to display a result of 5 from 0 + 5, not -3 (replaced by 0) from -8 + 5.

Comment: it dépends of the expression in "my computed expression". If it's a windowed function it should works

Comment: I definitely invite you to try it, for example using https://dbfiddle.uk/, but I can't see any way to get the desired result without using recursion or a UDF.  The problem is that a windowed function will modify the output, but the input remains unaffected, so the "sum over" of (10, -20, 5, 10) will calculate as (+10=10, 10-20=-10, 10-20+5=-5, 10-20+5+10=5) which it will display as (10, 0, 0, 5) but the correct output should be (10, 0, 5, 15)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via a [USER DEFINE TABLE FUNCTION](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html) to "manage" the state you want to carry

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION non_neg_sum(val float) RETURNS TABLE (out_sum float)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'{
  processRow: function (row, rowWriter) {
    this.sum += row.VAL;
    if(this.sum < 0)
        this.sum = 0;
    rowWriter.writeRow({OUT_SUM: this.sum})
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.sum = 0;
  }
}';
```

And used like so:

```
WITH input AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES ('2020-01-01', 8, 8),
        ('2020-01-02', 11, 19 ),
        ('2020-01-03', 30, 49 ),
        ('2020-01-04',-10, 39 ),
        ('2020-01-05',-12, 27 ),
        ('2020-01-06', -9, 18 ),
        ('2020-01-07',-26,  0 ),
        ('2020-01-08',  5,  5 ),
        ('2020-01-09',-23,  0 ),
        ('2020-01-10', 12, 12 ),
        ('2020-01-11', 14, 26 ) d(day,num,wanted)
)
SELECT d.*
    ,sum(d.num)over(order by day) AS simple_sum
    ,j.*
FROM input AS d,
  TABLE(non_neg_sum(d.num::float) OVER (ORDER BY d.day)) j
ORDER BY day
;
```

gives the results:

```
DAY          NUM     WANTED    SIMPLE_SUM    OUT_SUM
2020-01-01   8       8         8             8
2020-01-02   11      19        19            19
2020-01-03   30      49        49            49
2020-01-04   -10     39        39            39
2020-01-05   -12     27        27            27
2020-01-06   -9      18        18            18
2020-01-07   -26     0         -8            0
2020-01-08   5       5         -3            5
2020-01-09   -23     0         -26           0
2020-01-10   12      12        -14           12
2020-01-11   14      26        0             26
```

Comment: Great answer. I gave you an upvote, and even suggested this option to the client, but in the end I had to give Gordon Linoff the checkmark because his answer didn't require a UDF.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fair enough, if your want an answer that works in a read-only account

Answer (score 1):

Another UDF solution:

```
select d, x, conditional_sum(x) from values 
  ('2020-01-01',   8), 
  ('2020-01-02',  11), 
  ('2020-01-03',  30), 
  ('2020-01-04', -10), 
  ('2020-01-05', -12), 
  ('2020-01-06',  -9), 
  ('2020-01-07', -26), 
  ('2020-01-08',   5), 
  ('2020-01-09', -23), 
  ('2020-01-10',  12), 
  ('2020-01-11',  14)
  t(d,x)
order by d;
```

where `conditional_sum` is defined as:

```
create or replace function conditional_sum(X float) 
returns float 
language javascript 
volatile
as 
$$
    if (!('sum' in this)) this.sum = 0
    return this.sum = (X+this.sum)<0 ? 0 : this.sum+X 
$$;
```

Comment: Nice, I was thinking it should be do able with a normal UDF function. The down side of this version is if your data is partitioned or if you have enough rows, the UDF is not running on the same cores, so the results will be wrong.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I gave you an upvote, but I had to give Gordon Linoff the checkmark because his answer didn't require a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Demo :

```
WITH input AS
(   SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('2020-01-01', 8, 8),
        ('2020-01-02', 11, 19 ),
        ('2020-01-03', 30, 49 ),
        ('2020-01-04',-10, 39 ),
        ('2020-01-05',-12, 27 ),
        ('2020-01-06', -9, 18 ),
        ('2020-01-07',-26,  0 ),
        ('2020-01-08',  5,  5 ),
        ('2020-01-09',-23,  0 ),
        ('2020-01-10', 12, 12 ),
        ('2020-01-11', 14, 26 ),
        ('2020-01-12', 3,  26 )) AS d (day,num,wanted)
)
SELECT *, sum(num)over(order by day) AS CUM_SUM,
       CASE SIGN(sum(num)over(order by day)) 
          WHEN -1 THEN 0 
          ELSE sum(num)over(order by day) 
       END AS Actual
FROM   input 
ORDER BY day;
```

Return :

```
day                num      wanted     CUM_SUM      Actual
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2020-01-01           8           8           8           8
2020-01-02          11          19          19          19
2020-01-03          30          49          49          49
2020-01-04         -10          39          39          39
2020-01-05         -12          27          27          27
2020-01-06          -9          18          18          18
2020-01-07         -26           0          -8           0
2020-01-08           5           5          -3           0
2020-01-09         -23           0         -26           0
2020-01-10          12          12         -14           0
2020-01-11          14          26           0           0
2020-01-12           3          26           3           3
```

I add one more row to your test values… to demonstrate the final conditionnal sum is 3

Comment: This is not the desired output.  The output of your sum function needs to match the numbers in your "wanted" column.  Also with the row you added the last value in the "wanted" column should be 29.