# Running Total UDF ( user defined function ) with a window function is throwing 'Failed to coerce output value ''

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, window-functions, bigquery-udf

Input Dataset :

| Date | ID | Number | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 8 | 8 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 11.5 | 19.5 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | -20 | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | -5 | 5 |
| 2020-01-06 | 2 | -9 | 0 |
| 2020-01-07 | 2 | 26 | 26 |
| 2020-01-08 | 2 | 5 | 31 |
| 2020-01-09 | 2 | -23 | 8 |
| 2020-01-10 | 2 | -10.5 | 0 |
| 2020-01-11 | 2 | 5 | 5 |

I am trying to create a custom running total that resets to 0 everytime the running total dips below 0.

My code

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION conditional_sum(X ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js as r"""
    if (!('sum' in this)) this.sum =0
    return this.sum = (X + this.sum) <0 ? 0 : this.sum + X
""";
select *,conditional_sum(array_agg(number) over (partition by ID order by Date)) as run_sum from tbl
```

The error that I get is

```
 Failed to coerce output value "11.5,-20" to type FLOAT64. Bad double value
```

I borrowed this code from [Running total of positive and negative numbers where the sum cannot go below zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829731/running-total-of-positive-and-negative-numbers-where-the-sum-cannot-go-below-zer) and it works well without the window function and arrary_agg. But I need the window function because I need to apply the conditional sum to multiple IDs in Bigquery SQL

The other udf errors don't deal with window functions

Comment: Your code is treating your fields as strings and concatenating them, rather than adding them. Then when it tries to cast the string to a float, it predictably fails

Comment: but I am passing array_agg(number) which is the float array. what do I change to correct this error?

Answer (score 2):

Please add a for loop in the JavaScript code. Generate the array only to the current row.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION conditional_sum(X ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js as r"""
var cur=0;
var out=[];
  for(let x of X){
    cur+=x*1;
    if(cur<0) cur=0;
    //out.push(cur)
  }
  return cur;
  //  return out;
""";
With tbl as (
SELECT '2020-01-01' AS Date, 1 AS ID, 8 AS Number, 8 AS Desired
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-02', 1, 11.5, 19.5
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-03', 1, -20, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-04', 1, 10, 10
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-05', 1, -5, 5
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-06', 2, -9, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-07', 2, 26, 26
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-08', 2, 5, 31
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-09', 2, -23, 8
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-10', 2, -10.5, 0
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-11', 2, 5, 5
)

select *,conditional_sum([1.1,2,1]),
string_agg(cast(number as float64) || '' ) over win1,
conditional_sum(array_agg(cast(number as float64)) over win1 ) as run_sum 
from tbl
window win1 as (partition by ID order by Date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```